# Clear columns value based another columbs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this amazing Script. It put a timestamp based on "another Column"

Could someone help make it to clear timestamp when "another column" also cleared >> Done thankyou for **idkfurw**

here is the final script after update from **idkfurw**

```js
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+7";
  var time_format = "dd-MM-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Pasien";
  var timeStampColName = "Tgl Keluar";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Form'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
 
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) 
  
  { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
  
  if (sheet.getRange(index, updateCol).isBlank()) {
  sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1).clearContent();
}
else 
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, time_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) 
  
  { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!

if (sheet.getRange(index, updateCol).isBlank()) {
  sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1).clearContent();
}
else {

    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, time_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: @idffurw thankyou for responding. I got this result : Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ TIme.gs:7

Comment: What is the [type of the execution](https://script.google.com/home/executions)? Have you run from the editor?

Comment: @idkfurw yes it error on editor run, But it works very well on my worksheets. Thankyou for resolving this matter